# How to rename a kernel file

Tags: kernel, bluetooth

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 and my Bluetooth connection isn't working.  I've learned from several posts that a necessary part of the remedy is to rename the kernel file **BCM4356A2-13d3-3485.hcd** to **BCM4354A2-13d3-3485.hcd**.  Not being a kernel maven, I don' know what directory that file lives in.  It's also unclear to what else I need to do so that the change is seen by the kernel.

Here's what I get when I follow PJSingh's
suggestion:

```
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:~$ cd /lib
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:/lib$ sudo find . -name "*.hcd"
[sudo] password for pwa: 
./firmware/brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cb.hcd
./firmware/brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd
./firmware/brcm/BCM-0bb4-0306.hcd
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:/lib$ 
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:/lib$ cd /usr
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:/usr$ sudo find . -name "*.hcd"
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:/usr$ ./lib/firmware/brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd
bash: ./lib/firmware/brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd: No such file or directory
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:/usr$ ./lib/firmware/brcm/BCM-0bb4-0306.hcd
bash: ./lib/firmware/brcm/BCM-0bb4-0306.hcd: No such file or directory
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:/usr$ cd /
```

It's hard to follow what is going on with the long lines and the several levels of quotation, but the essential point is this: the files that turn up don't have  names that start with**BCM435**.

Comment: Here's what I get when I run the commands suggested by PJ Singh:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in...

```
/lib/firmware/brcm
```

...and...

```
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm
```

Here are the commands I used, in case you need to adapt them to suit your needs.

```
cd /lib
sudo find . -name "*.hcd"
./firmware/brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd
./firmware/brcm/BCM-0bb4-0306.hcd

cd /usr
sudo find . -name "*.hcd"
./lib/firmware/brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd
./lib/firmware/brcm/BCM-0bb4-0306.hcd
```

In the past, I've had success placing the module in `/lib/firmware/brcm`, but it wouldn't hurt to also replace it in the `/usr/lib/firmware/brcm` as well, if you find it there. (Keep an eye out for sim-links to the module in these directories).

Regarding the second part of your question, I think you need to use the [modprobe](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/modprobe.8.html) command after placing the file in the correct location and renaming it.

1. Remove the current Bluetooth module from the kernel (if it is loaded).

   ```
   sudo modprobe -r btusb
   ```
2. Load the new/updated Bluetooth module into the kernel.

   ```
   sudo modprobe btusb
   ```

I believe the kernel will automatically load the module subsequent reboots.

Comment: pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:/lib$ sudo find . -name "*.hcd"
[sudo] password for pwa: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for pwa: 
./firmware/brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cb.hcd
./firmware/brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd
./firmware/brcm/BCM-0bb4-0306.hcd
pwa@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:/lib$

Comment: Following PJSingh's suggestion:

Comment: Paul, the good news is, you now know where the bluetooth driver(s) are supposed to be placed on your system. But I don't think simply renaming a kernel module is going to solve your problem. You should start with determining precicely which hardware bluetooth device adapter your system actually has. Then you can figure out which device driver is correct for your adapter. Open a new question; I suggest asking something like "How to enable bluetooth on HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx?" Definitely include the output of `lsusb | grep Bluetooth` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` in your question.